# what file I need to create to work date archive links?

Tags: categories, archives, author

I am using my own theme.

**my archive.php..**

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12, 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
<?php wp_list_categories( array ( 'title_li'=> '' , 'show_count' => 1))?>
php wp_list_authors( array ('optioncount' => 1)); ?>
```

I have **author.php** and **category.php**

so the linkes generated by `wp_list_categories` and `wp_list_authors`

but if click on the links generated by `<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12, 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>` it's just post back the archive.php.

eg: If I click **dec/2013** from `www.mydomain.com/blog/archive` then the URL become `www.mydomain.com/blog/dec/2013/12` with same content of `www.mydomain.com/blog/archive`
why? what I wanna do to solve this?

---

If I click **category1** on `www.mydomain.com/blog/archive`then the URL become `www.mydomain.com/blog/archive/category1` and content generated from **archive.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview) `archive.php` is very generic template, used for all kinds of archives.

Going by same chart if you want to add template, which applies to all date archives you should name it `date.php`.

Comment: I've added the following code to my **date.php **
but is shows all the post how can I get the post according to the arcihive month/year?
`$date1 = get_query_var('date');
    
     // The Query
     query_posts( array ( 'date' => $date1, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
   
     // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    
    <li>
    <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?> <br/>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
     </li></br>
   
     <?php endwhile;
   
     // Reset Query
     wp_reset_query();?>`

Comment: @RiffazStarr why are you using `query_posts()` there at all then? Also it seems like entirely new question, different from template hierarchy. Would make sense to ask it separately.

Comment: I've aske that here 'http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126237/how-to-get-the-date-dynamically-from-archive-php-to-date-php?noredirect=1#comment178035_126237`
can you please have a look there?