# How to get the date dynamically from archive.php to date.php?

Tags: archives, date

My **archive.php**

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12, 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?><br/>
```

My **date.php**

```
$date1 = get_query_var('date');

              // The Query
              query_posts( array ( 'date' => $date1, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

              // The Loop
             while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <li>
                <?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?> <br/>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
              </li></br>

              <?php endwhile;

              // Reset Query
              wp_reset_query();?>
```

but it show all the posts form the blog.
how can I edit it to show the post from the proper year and month when some one click the link generated by arhive.php?

Comment: How are these two files interlinked ? Can you please explain it more.

Comment: these files are placed in to my theme folder.
my theme folder has index.php, style.css, archive.php, category.php, author.php and date.php.
so when I click links from `www.mydomain.com/blogarchive` that will be redirected to the proper page. isn't it?
eg: if I click **archive by author** then it will be redirected to author.php. its a default action by wordpress. am i right?

Comment: get rid of the call to `query_posts` and just output the default query.

Comment: @Milo could you please explain bit more? can I get what I want as I mentioned above if I use the default query instead of `query_post`?

Comment: now on my `date.php` I have the following codes only.
`while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?> <br/>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li></br>     <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>'
when I click **Dec, 2011** on `www.mydomain.com/blog/archive` then the URL becomes `www.mydomain.com/blog/2013/12` that's currect. but it shows only three posts.

Comment: even I add the `$date1 = get_query_var($query_string.'date'); get_posts( array ( 'date' => $date1, 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );' above the loop.
how can I fix it ?

Comment: The main query already queries for the correct date parameters, if all you want to do is change the number of posts per page, then search this site and codex for [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working very fine after I made some changes / adding on two php files `function.php` and `date.php`

**function.php**

```
function wpa_date_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin()
        && $query->is_date()
        && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_date_posts_per_page' );
```

**date.php**

```
<?php get_header(); 
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
            echo the_title() . '<br/><br/>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
get_footer();?>
```

**archive.php**

```
<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'limit' => 12, 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?><br/>
```

very special thanks to @milo